# 10060 error when connecting MariaDB on VM on Compute Engine of Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, mariadb, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

1. Created a VM on Compute Engine of Google Cloud Platform.
2. Installed Maria DB. Configured binding to 0.0.0.0.
3. Created a firewall rule to allow access to 3306  in the IP ranged 0.0.0.0/0. Tagged it as "mysql-open" and Added it as a network tag in the VM instance detail. I also chose the option to log the connection.
4. When I try to connect from MySQL workbench to the public address of the VM Instance with 3306 as the Port, I get  a
   10060 error.
   The user ID used to connect was given full GRANT and was like 'testuser'@'%'.
   Below is the log entry. Which seems to show that the firewall rule worked.

```
      "insertId": "epk9z8g1zjxknf",
      "jsonPayload": {
        "instance": {
          "project_id": "XXXX",
          "vm_name": "XXX",
          "region": "us-east4",
          "zone": "us-east4-c"
        },
        "connection": {
          "src_port": 44826,
          "dest_ip": "10.150.0.5",
          "protocol": 6,
          "dest_port": 3306,
          "src_ip": "198.199.98.246"
        },
        "remote_location": {
          "city": "San Francisco",
          "continent": "America",
          "country": "usa",
          "region": "California"
        },
        "rule_details": {
          "priority": 2000,
          "ip_port_info": [
            {
              "port_range": [
                "3306"
              ],
              "ip_protocol": "TCP"
            }
          ],
          "source_range": [
            "0.0.0.0/0"
          ],
          "reference": "network:default/firewall:mysql-open",
          "action": "ALLOW",
          "direction": "INGRESS"
        },
        "vpc": {
          "project_id": "XXXX",
          "vpc_name": "default",
          "subnetwork_name": "default"
        },
        "disposition": "ALLOWED"
      },
      "resource": {
        "type": "gce_subnetwork",
        "labels": {
          "subnetwork_id": "2510359252254555075",
          "project_id": "XXXX",
          "subnetwork_name": "default",
          "location": "us-east4-c"
        }
      },
      "timestamp": "2020-11-05T14:12:33.819891417Z",
      "logName": "projects/XXXX/logs/compute.googleapis.com%2Ffirewall",
      "receiveTimestamp": "2020-11-05T14:12:39.166067521Z"
    }
```

Comment: That error code indicates that the connction failed or the server didn't respond. Most likely a firewall or port forwarding issue, or the server being down.

Comment: I agree with Alejandro, your issue seems like related to firewall or Port forwarding . Please see the similar issue and answer posted on another Stack Overflow [Case- 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56715495/not-able-to-login-in-google-cloud-storage-sql-instance). Please also provide your feedback .

Comment: @sohail Alvi , Alejandro, the issue that you are referring to is related to a  Cloud SQL instance and how to access from outside.  Here I have created a MariaDB instance in a VM of Cloud Compute Engine and the access is not happening from outside, though the log says that the firewall rule worked. I anyways created a Cloud SQL instance and I am accessing that from the VM using PHP. So I think I do not need to solve the origian problem. Thank You for your time and guidance.

Comment: @ Sanker, from the error message 10060 , it is deduced that there must be some issue with your instance or OS Firewall configuration . Did you follow the documentation [1](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/setup-mysql#install_mysql) for the installation of your maria DB on VM-Instance ? . Please provide the reference document you used to install the mariaDB . As you said , you created another Cloud SQL instance and you are able to access the VM from your PHP application, what changes you have made to your new Cloud SQL instance that are different from the Maria-db instance ?

Comment: @ Sankar,  As this is not a portal to share confidential information and If you want you can open an issue tracker by following the document - [1](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) and we will investigate the issue and you can share more information.

Comment: @Sohail Alvi, I created another instance and deleted the old instance and it seems to be working now. Thanks for the document that you provided.